# Heroku No Such App While Using a Sub domain

Tags: heroku

I am trying to point a custom domain as a CNAME at my heroku app. My domain is heroku.mikelyons.org and I have it pointed at mikelyons.herokuapp.com.

```
$ host heroku.mikelyons.org
heroku.mikelyons.org is an alias for mikelyons.herokuapp.com.
mikelyons.herokuapp.com has address 54.243.121.176

$ host mikelyons.herokuapp.com
mikelyons.herokuapp.com has address 54.243.121.176

$ heroku domains
=== mikelyons Domain Names
heroku.mikelyons.org
mikelyons.herokuapp.com
www.heroku.mikelyons.org
```

I added these domains with domains:add. But when I go to heroku.mikelyons.org I get a: "Heroku | No such app" page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all looks ok, there have been API issues this morning with Heroku which could explain the problem. I'd put it down to that.

UPDATE: But it looks like it's working now ;)

Comment: It was working for a moment, but it seems to have stopped working again.

Comment: in which case, I'd raise a ticket and get Heroku support to look into it.